# Laravel 5.2 Filesystem FTP TSL

Tags: php, ftp, laravel-5

I use filesystem in laravel 5.2 and when i try connect to simple FTP without TSL, evertyhing works fine. But when i try connect to FTP with TSL i have error 
"ftp cleartext sessions not accepted".

Mayby I am stupid but i dont know hove configure drive in config/filesystem.php with tsl.

This all parametrs in FTP Adapter

- 'host',
- 'port',
- 'username',
- 'password',
- 'ssl',
- 'timeout',
- 'root',
- 'permPrivate',
- 'permPublic',
- 'passive',
- 'transferMode',
- 'systemType',
- 'ignorePassiveAddress',

Can you give me example configuration with TSL Or lib works FTP TSL to laravel 5.